# Can I duplicate an AWS CodeBuild project?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I currently have a CodeBuild build project. It has many configurations & I'm looking to reuse it as a base for my other projects. I'm not looking to duplicate repository(s) within a CodeBuild project but the project itself.

Can I duplicate an AWS CodeBuild project?

Comment: isnt better to use the same pipeline build step parametrized ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I duplicate an AWS CodeBuild project?

**No, currently there is no native support for duplicating build projects.**

Using IaC, such as [Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/codebuild_project), would allow you to redeploy the same build project and in effect, 'duplicate' it. Alternatively, you may also be able to programmatically retrieve the configuration of the existing project using [`aws codebuild batch-get-projects`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/codebuild/batch-get-projects.html), modify it as needed, and then create a new project using [`aws codebuild create-project`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/codebuild/create-project.html).

Comment: Thank you @ermiya! Exactly the information I was looking for.